# PCA output looks weird for a kmeans scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-learn, pca

After doing PCA on my data and plotting the kmeans clusters, my plot looks really weird. The centers of the clusters and scatter plot of the points do not make sense to me. Here is my code:

```
#clicks, conversion, bounce and search are lists of values.
clicks=[2,0,0,8,7,...]
conversion = [1,0,0,6,0...]
bounce = [2,4,5,0,1....]

X = np.array([clicks,conversion, bounce]).T
y = np.array(search)

num_clusters = 5

pca=PCA(n_components=2, whiten=True)
data2D = pca.fit_transform(X)

print data2D
    >>> [[-0.07187948 -0.17784291]
     [-0.07173769 -0.26868727]
     [-0.07173789 -0.26867958]
     ..., 
     [-0.06942414 -0.25040886]
     [-0.06950897 -0.19591147]
     [-0.07172973 -0.2687937 ]]

km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1)
km.fit_transform(X)

labels=km.labels_
centers2D = pca.fit_transform(km.cluster_centers_)

colors=['#000000','#FFFFFF','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF']
col_map=dict(zip(set(labels),colors))
label_color = [col_map[l] for l in labels]

plt.scatter( data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c=label_color)
plt.hold(True)
plt.scatter(centers2D[:,0], centers2D[:,1],  marker='x', c='r')
plt.show()
```

The red crosses are the center of the clusters. Any help would be great.
[image]

Comment: Make up -- or look up -- example data for which you know what the output should be, and see if using your code on that works.

Comment: can you provide a link to access your data if that's not proprietary? for example, a dropbox share link with your csv file.

Comment: @jxn Just to double check with you about the raw data: I see 225875 out of the total 289804 `clicks` records are `Null` and 288926 out of the total 289804 `bounce_cnt` records are `Null`. Is this correct? With such a high percent of missing-values, those two features are barely useful.

Comment: Yes, i tried not including them in the model and just tried using freq, median, and others and still i got the weird shape.

Comment: @jxn Another observation is that the other two features `freq` and `conversion_cnt` lack of variation. I mean 213773/289804 records on `freq` is 1.0 and 268124/289804 records on `conversion_cnt` is 0.0. `PCA` rely on valid covariance estimation, and because the data lack of sufficient variation, I doubt the usefulness of `PCA`. Let me think about how to tackle this problem and will update you afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# read your data, replace 'stackoverflow.csv' with your file path
df = pd.read_csv('stackoverflow.csv', usecols=[0, 2, 4], names=['freq', 'visit_length', 'conversion_cnt'], header=0).dropna()
df.describe()

Out[3]: 
              freq  visit_length  conversion_cnt
count  289705.0000   289705.0000     289705.0000
mean        0.2624       20.7598          0.0748
std         0.4399       55.0571          0.2631
min         0.0000        1.0000          0.0000
25%         0.0000        6.0000          0.0000
50%         0.0000       10.0000          0.0000
75%         1.0000       21.0000          0.0000
max         1.0000     2500.0000          1.0000

# binarlize freq and conversion_cnt
df.freq = np.where(df.freq > 1.0, 1, 0)
df.conversion_cnt = np.where(df.conversion_cnt > 0.0, 1, 0)

feature_names = df.columns
X_raw = df.values

transformer = PCA(n_components=2)
X_2d = transformer.fit_transform(X_raw)
# over 99.9% variance captured by 2d data
transformer.explained_variance_ratio_

Out[4]: array([  9.9991e-01,   6.6411e-05])

# do clustering
estimator = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++', n_init=10, verbose=1)
estimator.fit(X_2d)

labels = estimator.labels_
colors = ['#000000','#FFFFFF','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF']
col_map=dict(zip(set(labels),colors))
label_color = [col_map[l] for l in labels]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X_2d[:,0], X_2d[:,1], c=label_color)
ax.scatter(estimator.cluster_centers_[:,0], estimator.cluster_centers_[:,1], marker='x', s=50, c='r')
```

[image]

`KMeans` tries to minimize within-group Euclidean distance, and this may or may not be appropriate for your data. Just based on the graph, I would consider a `Gaussian Mixture Model` to do the unsupervised clustering.

Also, if you have superior knowledge on which observations might be classified into which category/label, you can do a semi-supervised learning.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the advice and pointing me in the right direction! Definitely need to do more descriptive statistics before processing the data.

Answer (score 5):

Your ordering of PCA and KMeans is screwing things up...

### Here is what you need to do:

1. Normalize your data.
2. Perform `PCA` on `X` to reduce the dimensions from 5 to 2 and produce `Data2D`
3. Normalize again
4. Cluster `Data2D` with `KMeans`
5. Plot the `Centroids` on top of `Data2D`.

### Where as, here is what you have done above:

1. Perform `PCA` on `X` to reduce the dimensions from 5 to 2 to produce `Data2D`
2. Cluster the original data, `X`, in 5 dimensions.
3. Perform a separate `PCA` on your cluster centroids, which produces a completely different 2D subspace for the centroids.
4. Plot the PCA reduced `Data2D` with the `PCA` reduced centroids on top even though these no longer are coupled properly.

### Normalization:

Take a look at the code below and you'll see that it puts the centroids right where they need to be.  The normalization is key and is completely reversible.  ALWAYS normalize your data when you cluster as the distance metrics need to move through all of the spaces equally.  Clustering is one of the most important times to normalize your data, but in general... ALWAYS NORMALIZE :-)

### A heuristic discussion that goes beyond your original question:

The entire point of dimensionality reduction is to make the KMeans clustering easier and to project out dimensions which don't add to the variance of the data.  So you should pass the reduced data to your clustering algorithm.  I'll add that there are very few 5D datasets which can be projected down to 2D without throwing out a lot of variance i.e. look at the PCA diagnostics to see whether 90% of the original variance has been preserved.  If not, then you might not want to be so aggressive in your PCA.

### New Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

# read your data, replace 'stackoverflow.csv' with your file path
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/angus/Desktop/Downloads/stackoverflow.csv', usecols[0, 2, 4],names=['freq', 'visit_length', 'conversion_cnt'],header=0).dropna()

df.describe()

#Normalize the data
df_norm = (df - df.mean()) / (df.max() - df.min())

num_clusters = 5

pca=PCA(n_components=2)
UnNormdata2D = pca.fit_transform(df_norm)

# Check the resulting varience
var = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
print "Varience after PCA: ",var

#Normalize again following PCA: data2D
data2D = (UnNormdata2D - UnNormdata2D.mean()) / (UnNormdata2D.max()-UnNormdata2D.min())

print "Data2D: "
print data2D

km = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1)
km.fit_transform(data2D)

labels=km.labels_
centers2D = km.cluster_centers_

colors=['#000000','#FFFFFF','#FF0000','#00FF00','#0000FF']
col_map=dict(zip(set(labels),colors))
label_color = [col_map[l] for l in labels]

plt.scatter( data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], c=label_color)
plt.hold(True)
plt.scatter(centers2D[:,0], centers2D[:,1],marker='x',s=150.0,color='purple')
plt.show()
```

### Plot:

[image: plot from code above]

### Output:

```
Varience after PCA:  [ 0.65725709  0.29875307]
Data2D: 
[[-0.00338421 -0.0009403 ]
[-0.00512081 -0.00095038]
[-0.00512081 -0.00095038]
..., 
[-0.00477349 -0.00094836]
[-0.00373153 -0.00094232]
[-0.00512081 -0.00095038]]
Initialization complete
Iteration  0, inertia 51.225
Iteration  1, inertia 38.597
Iteration  2, inertia 36.837
...
...
Converged at iteration 31
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, however i still see a similar shaped chart

Comment: Please post some actual data then, so we can varify.

Comment: Yes. It was mainly due to my data being too sparse.

Comment: Can you please re-post the data so I can pull it down.  I didn't have a chance to look at it yesterday and want to take a look.  While the binarization might work, there's no need for it and it dilutes the solution (e.g. makes it less accurate).  I think a much more sound solution is to just normalize the data.

Comment: Take a look at my answer now... You'll see that it puts the centroids right where they need to be and there is no binarization.  The normalization is completely reversible, where as binarization is not.  ALWAYS normalize your data when you cluster as the distance metrics need to move through all of the spaces equally.  Clustering is one of the most important times to normalize your data, but in general... ALWAYS NORMALIZE :-)

Comment: thanks for this! do you know why the plots are all along the axis?

Comment: That's just how your data is.  You could get rid of outliers via dff=df[np.abs(df-df.mean())<=(2*df.std())].  But it pretty much looks the same.  If your data is zero inflated you could test for normality and then try some sort of transformation like an inverse hyperbolic tangent or something.